# Как выровнять форму подачи заявки?

Tags: html, css

Есть форма и текст которую надо разместить как на картинке. Никак не могу выровнять как надо.  На сколько я понял `input`-и и `textarea` надо обернуть в отдельные блоки и их потом размещать? Помогите пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.application{
 display: flex;
 padding-top: 39px;
 padding-left: 51px;
 width: 195px;
 height: 210px;
}
.application_txt span{
 display: inline-block;
}
.application_txt #title{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 48px;
 font-weight: bold;

}
.callback{
 clear:both; 
 float: right;
}
#message{
 width: 315px;
 height: 180px;
 resize: none;
 border-color: #0cb1aa;
}
.callback input[type="text"]{
 width: 310px;
 height: 40px;
 border-color: #0cb1aa;
}
.fields {
 clear:both; 
 text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="application">
  <div class="application_txt">
    <span id="title">Подать заявку</span>
    <span id="txt">Заполните форму, чтобы записаться на консультацию – это первый шаг к зачислению в школу. Количество мест ограничено</span>
  </div>
<!-- Форма заявки -->
<section class="callback">
  <form action="" id="callback">
    <div class="fields">
      <label >Имя<br>
        <input type="text"></label>
      <label >Телефон<br>
        <input type="text"></label>
      <label >E-mail<br>
        <input type="text"></label>
      </div>
      <div class="mess">
        <label>Сообщение<br>
          <textarea name="" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        </label>
      </div>
    <button class="send" type="submit">Подать заявку</button>
  </form>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: > надо обернуть в отдельные блоки и их потом размещать? -  ДА

Comment: @Arsen Да надо правильно сделать каркас, ну сверстать так как на картинке.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan,  не понял ваш коментарий к моей....

Comment: @Arsen Да верно

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan -  "не понял ваш коментарий к моей" это не вопрос был(там нет вопросительного знака). Возможно вы и не поняли мой первый коммент, там я цитирую вопрос Swartex (>  - это знак цитирования),  Swartex  справшивает  " > На сколько я понял input-и и textarea надо обернуть в отдельные блоки и их потом размещать? "  и я ему отвечаю - ДА

Answer (score 0):

Например вот так:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.application {
  padding-top: 39px;
  padding-left: 51px;
  width: 900px;
  position: relative
}

.application:before,
.application:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.application:after {
  clear: both;
}

.application_txt {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}

.col {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.application_txt span {
  display: inline-block;
}

.application_txt #title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.callback {
  float: right;
  width: 66%;
  position: relative
}

.callback:before,
.callback:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.callback:after {
  clear: both;
}

#message {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  resize: none;
  border-color: #0cb1aa;
}

.callback input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border-color: #0cb1aa;
}

.fields {
  text-align: left;
}

.mess {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="application">
  <div class="application_txt">
    <span id="title">Подать заявку</span>
    <span id="txt">Заполните форму, чтобы записаться на консультацию – это первый шаг к зачислению в школу. Количество мест ограничено</span>
  </div>
  <!-- Форма заявки -->
  <section class="callback">
    <form action="" id="callback">
      <div class="fields">
        <div class=col>
          <label>Имя<br>
        <input type="text"></label>
          <label>Телефон<br>
        <input type="text"></label>
          <label>E-mail<br>
        <input type="text"></label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class=col>
        <div class="mess">
          <label>Сообщение<br>
          <textarea name="" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        </label>
          <button class="send" type="submit">Подать заявку</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете воспользоваться flex версткой - разделить на блоки (у вас их 3) и поместить их в отдельный контейнер. А у него уже прописать необходимые атрибуты. Пример ниже.

```css
.application{
 display: flex;
 padding-top: 39px;
 padding-left: 51px;
 width: 195px;
 height: 210px;
}
.application_txt span{
 display: inline-block;
}
.application_txt #title{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 48px;
 font-weight: bold;

}
.callback{
 clear:both; 
 float: right;
}
#message{
 width: 315px;
 height: 180px;
 resize: none;
 border-color: #0cb1aa;
}
.callback input[type="text"]{
 width: 310px;
 height: 40px;
 border-color: #0cb1aa;
}
.fields {
 clear:both; 
 text-align: left;
}
.fields{
  display: flex;
  justify-content center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.column{
  flex: 1 1 33%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="application">

<!-- Форма заявки -->
<section class="callback">
  <form action="" id="callback">  
    <div class="fields">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="application_txt">
          <span id="title">Подать заявку</span>
          <span id="txt">Заполните форму, чтобы записаться на консультацию – это первый шаг к зачислению в школу. Количество мест ограничено</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <label >Имя<br>
          <input type="text"></label>
        <label >Телефон<br>
          <input type="text"></label>
        <label >E-mail<br>
          <input type="text"></label>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="mess">
          <label>Сообщение<br>
            <textarea name="" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
          </label>
        </div>
        <button class="send" type="submit">Подать заявку</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться флекс-боксами

```css
.application{
 display: flex;
 padding-top: 39px;
 padding-left: 51px;
 width: 195px;
 height: 210px;
}
.application_txt span{
 display: inline-block;
}
.application_txt #title{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 48px;
 font-weight: bold;

}
.callback{
 clear:both; 
 float: right;
}
.callback form {
  display:flex;
}
#message{
 width: 315px;
 height: 180px;
 resize: none;
  float:right;
 border-color: #0cb1aa;
}
.callback input[type="text"]{
 width: 310px;
 height: 40px;
 border-color: #0cb1aa;
}
.fields {
 clear:both; 
 text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="application">
  <div class="application_txt">
    <span id="title">Подать заявку</span>
    <span id="txt">Заполните форму, чтобы записаться на консультацию – это первый шаг к зачислению в школу. Количество мест ограничено</span>
  </div>
<!-- Форма заявки -->
<section class="callback">
  <form action="" id="callback">
    <div class="fields">
      <label >Имя<br>
        <input type="text"></label>
      <label >Телефон<br>
        <input type="text"></label>
      <label >E-mail<br>
        <input type="text"></label>
      </div>
      <div class="mess">
        <label>Сообщение<br>
          <textarea name="" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        </label>
            <button class="send" type="submit">Подать заявку</button>

      </div>
  </form>
</section>
</div>
```